# Why printing double time backslash?

Tags: python

I am curious to know why?

[image]

`r"\\"` print `\\\\`

Comment: The backslash "escapes" the quote character that would otherwise close the string. What you are left with is an unclosed string and python is expecting the string to terminate - not the file to end.

Comment: In addition - for the future - it would by MUCH easier to just copy and paste the code instead of taking a screenshot, uploading it and then pasting the an image of text.

Comment: @Lix, Thanks and I will keep in mind your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse with the immediate output of python and `print` statements.
Hopefully, The following example will clarify your doubts.

```
In [5]: a = "a\nb"
In [6]: a
Out[6]: 'a\nb'
In [7]: print a
a
b
In [8]: a = r'\\'
In [9]: a
Out[9]: '\\\\'
In [10]: print a
\\
```

If your doubt is regarding `raw string` (`r''` represents raw string), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/4954434) is a good read.
Quoting the essentials here:

> A "raw string literal" is a slightly different syntax for a string
>   literal, in which a backslash, \, is taken as meaning "just a
>   backslash" (except when it comes right before a quote that would
>   otherwise terminate the literal) -- no "escape sequences" to represent
>   newlines, tabs, backspaces, form-feeds, and so on. In normal string
>   literals, each backslash must be doubled up to avoid being taken as
>   the start of an escape sequence.